# How can I add a popup notification using Swing inside the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I need to add a notification to my swing application to display only for incomming messages, I try with JPanel inside the Jframe but when I this the main window is covered.

Here is a part of my code

```
public class MainUI extends JFrame {
    private void constructUI() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(getDesktopPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(getStatusBar(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(getNotificationsPanel());
    }
}
```

And my idea of notification:

[image]

The notification is a JPanel but it is blocking the view of the JFrame.

Comment: Please improve your question. Try to write it with an eye towards our perspective: folks who have no clue as to what your current code looks like, what your specific goal is, or what errors you might be seeing. Show us pertinent code, explain the details, etc... Putting just a little more effort into this question will likely pay you big dividends.

Comment: Why don't you just create another JDialog/JFrame and set it always on top?
Without further details this is all i can suggest. What do you need specifically?

Comment: I add some code and an image to show the idea of what I want to do

Comment: Do you perhaps mean [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is: calling `add(component);` on a component with BorderLayout is the same as calling `add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);`.

That's why your notifications panel is blocking the center view of the frame.

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html